# installed python 3.10 but not recognised in terminal (mac OS monterey)

Tags: python, macos

I have used both the python installer and brew to try to install python 3.10 but version 3.9.12 shows up in terminal, even though python 3.10 can be seen in finder.

[screenshot showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH0KN.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're on macos Monterey, you have to set your `PATH` for your shell (`zsh` unless you've made a default shell change):

1. **For using Python 3.10 from the Installer**

   If you got Python 3.10 from the python.org installer, put a line like this in your `~/.zshrc` file:

   ```
   # somewhere in your ~/.zshrc, probably near the bottom
   export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
   ```
2. **For Python 3.10 from homebrew**

   Similar to above, but a different path

   ```
   # assuming you did "brew install python@3.10"
   # in your ~/.zshrc, near the bottom
   export PATH="$(brew --prefix python@3.10)/bin:$PATH"
   ```

---

Regardless of which option you pick, open up a new terminal instance or run `exec zsh` in an existing terminal and you should hopefully have the right python3 version running.

```
# In my own .zshrc, I did this...
# export PATH="$(brew --prefix python@3.10)/bin:$PATH"

> exec zsh
> python3 -V
Python 3.10.5
```

Answer (score -1):

On windows the version of python can be specified by tacking on
-versionNumber to your python terminal call

`python -3.1`